# How do I assign a new value to a row based on a condition in r?

Tags: r, assign

I want to analyse purchases individually. However, some client bought more than one time a product. Therefore I want to split these purchases. My data looks like:

```
Clientid        Conversion         Date
    1                No             1/01
    1                Yes            2/01
    1                No             3/01 
    1                No             4/01
    1                Yes            5/01
    1                No             6/01
    1                Yes            7/01
    2                No             3/04
    2                No             4/04
    2                Yes            5/04
    2                No             6/04
    2                Yes            7/04
```

I want to have output where all purchases are assigned to different clientid's. So if a customer does second or third purchase it need to generate a new client'id. In my example output I just filled it in with x, y and z because, but im looking for a function that could do that by itself.

My output has to look like:

````
Clientid        Conversion         Date
    1                No             1/01
    1                Yes            2/01
    x                No             3/01 
    x                No             4/01
    x                Yes            5/01
    y                No             6/01
    y                Yes            7/01
    2                No             3/04
    2                No             4/04
    2                Yes            5/04
    z                No             6/04
    z                Yes            7/04
```
Thanks for helping in advance.
````

Comment: Can you explain further how you derived the Clientid in your example output?

Comment: The x, y and z are just random assigned values. The most important is that the new generated client id's (x, y and z) are different from the original ones. I filled in x, y and z because it doesnt matter what values they are.

Comment: Why dont you just append the date to the ID? And even add a row index just in case there is more than one purchase in the same day?

Comment: Im not exaclty sure what you mean. How does that work?